# How to insert another control into TTabItem in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tabcontrol, tabitem

I would like to insert an additional `TText` into the "tabbed" part `TTabItem` of a `TTabControl`, so that I can have another text of a different color.

It seems a control can't be moved to that "tabbed" portion.

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear.  I have pasted an image to illustrate what i need.  I need to add a new TText to some position in the HOME bottom (area).  I don't want to add a new TabItem to the TabControl.  This new text position is of different color and size as the 'home' text.   Ideally, I'd like to have control where the 'new' green text is positioned exactly.

Comment: You could draw your custom text implementing the `onPaint` event of the TTabItem, but you will see your text on runtime only.

Comment: @AlexSawers If you could post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the requirement is to have a simple text displayed on a `TTabItem` this can be easily implemented using the `onPaint` event of the `TTabItem` control. So this code:

```
procedure TForm1.TabItem1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
var
  R: TRectF;
begin
  // Use only 1/3 top part of the canvas
  R:=RectF(ARect.Left, ARect.Top, ARect.Right, ARect.Bottom / 3);
  // Set font color and size
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Seagreen;
  Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
  // Draw text
  Canvas.FillText(R, 'New!', False, 1, [], TTextAlign.Center, TTextAlign.Center);
end;
```

Produces this:

[image: TabItem with custom text drawn on top]